# How to access a property of a class by its name?

Tags: c#, enums

I find it hard to clearly describe the case in a one-sentence title. Here is the example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public enum PersonProperties
{
    FirstName = 1,
    MiddleName = 2,
    LastName = 3
}
```

I am hoping to do this:

```
foreach (var p in Persons) {
var nameCollection=new List<string>();
foreach (var s in (SectionsEnum[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof (SectionsEnum)))
{
    nameCollection.Add(p.GetPropertyByName(s);
}
}
```

Now, how can we implement the `GetPropertyByName()` part?

Comment: Technically you can do it, but why in first place? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  Reflection may be able to help you if you are trying to get the properties of an object via the actual names of the properties.

Comment: My class have twenty some properties and I would like to retrieve the values in a loop instead of accessing them one by one.

Comment: Why don't you just have a get only property that returns a dictionary made up of all of the internal properties?

Comment: Dictionary? Not a good idea. It just looks redundant since we already have an enum. Any better solutions?

Comment: The enum sounds like it's just a key to the "dictionary" of properties anyway.  Reflection has this built into it though, so that's probably the path you should look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this directly using reflection:

```
public string GetPropertyByName(SectionsEnum s)
{
    var property = typeof(Person).GetProperty(s.ToString());
    return (string)property.GetValue(this);
}
```

Or maybe with a `switch`.

```
public string GetPropertyByName(SectionsEnum s)
{
    switch (s)
    {
        case SectionsEnum.FirstName:
            return this.FirstName;
        case SectionsEnum.MiddleName:
            return this.MiddleName;
        case SectionsEnum.LastName:
            return this.LastName;
        default:
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

But I'd ask if you wouldn't be better served by a wholly different approach, e.g. a list:

```
public IList<string> NameProperties
{
    get
    {
        return new[] { FirstName, MiddleName, LastName };
    }
}
```

Or instead of having `SectionsEnum`, use `Func`s:

```
//was
SectionsEnum s = SectionsEnum.FirstName;
//instead
Func<Person, string> nameFunc = p => p.FirstName;
string name = nameFunc(myPerson);
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be a good starting point for you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p = new Person() { FirstName ="a", MiddleName = "b", LastName = "c" };

            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            string[] enums = Enum.GetNames(typeof(PersonProperties));

            foreach(string e in enums)
            {
                result.Add(p.GetType().GetProperty(e).GetValue(p, null).ToString());
            }

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string e in enums)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", e, result[i++]));
            }

            Console.ReadKey(false);
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public enum PersonProperties
    {
        FirstName = 1,
        MiddleName = 2,
        LastName = 3
    }
}
```